# Wrong type of @types/elasticsearch SearchResponse

Tags: typescript, elasticsearch, http-status-codes, nestjs

When I use the ElasticsearchService of @nestjs/elasticsearch the result of the response doesnt match the type SearchResponse of @types/elasticsearch because SearchResponse is an object but I actually get an array with the SearchResponse object and a Http Status Code, does someone know how to turn this off?

Example:

```
[
  {
    ...,
    "aggregations": {
      "backendVersions": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "1.0.0",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  200
]
```

Comment: can you post an example of how you are using the elasticsearch service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ElasticsearchService of @nestjs/elasticsearch wraps the es client with [bindNodeCallback](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/bindNodeCallback), it's explained in the [doc](https://github.com/nestjs/elasticsearch#api-spec).

So this:

```js
client.search({
  index: 'my-index',
  body: { foo: 'bar' }
}, (err, body, statusCode, headers) => {
  if (err) console.log(err)
})
```

Will be transformed into an observable which will emit a value with the args from the callback minus the err in an array.

```js
service.search({
  index: 'my-index',
  body: { foo: 'bar' }
}).subscribe(value => {
  console.log(value); // [body, statusCode, headers]
});
```

You can't turn this off but you can use the elasticsearch client directly by using `getClient()`:

```js
const searchResponse = await service.getClient().search({
  index: 'my-index',
  body: { foo: 'bar' }
});
```

Also keep in mind there will be [breaking changes in @elastic/elasticsearch [7.x]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/breaking-changes.html):

```js
client.search({
  index: 'my-index',
  body: { foo: 'bar' }
}, (err, { body, statusCode, headers, warnings }) => {
  if (err) console.log(err)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) And do you know whats the difference between ElasticsearchService.search() and ElasticsearchService.getClient().search() because with the first one I cant pass more than one parameter. And what should I use?

Comment: @Alexander491 you can use `getClient` to get the unwrapped elasticsearch client. So if you want the non-observable API use `getClient.search`.